# How to provide an init method for empty arg constructor?

Tags: java, oop, serialization

I have some classes that should be `Serializable`, thus require an empty argument constructor.
Further I'd like to have some custom `init()` routine for all class implementation.

So far I had the `init()` just inside the no argument constructor. But as I now need an empty no-arg constructor for serialization, how can I ensure an auto-executed `init()` method for all implementations?

Example:

```
abstract class Foo implements Serializable {
   int id;

   Foo() {
      id = UUID.randomUUID();
   }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
   Bar() {}
   Bar(String param) {
      //...
   }
}
```

This is what I used to have. The `Foo()` constructor is always called for any implementations implicit. The implementation does not have to take any `UUID` generation into account.

How can I achieve the same when I have to necessarily make the `Foo()` an empty constructor for `Serialization`?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you need empty constructor?

Comment: The body does not have to be empty; it's just that the constructor argument list has to be empty.

Comment: A serializable class doesn't need to have parameterless constructor..

Comment: You need need a no argument constructor for `Foo` only if is not serializable and `Bar` is serializable.

Comment: As far my knowledge , it if we have combination of Superclass which is not serializable and subclass which is serializable then superclass shld have no arg constructor [not empty one]. In your case i dont see any need for no arg empty constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have some classes that should be Serializable, thus require an empty
>   argument constructor.

It is not mandatory . If a class or its super-class is serializable it is not mandatory to define  parameter-less constructor within that class until you are going to extend that class to some other class which is needed because of constructor chaining.